# Remote (IMAP) drafts not deleted when the message is sent

Tags: thunderbird, imap, outlook.com

I've got 2 accounts that use imap-mail.outlook.com/smtp-mail.outlook.com:

- A personal one
- A work/school one

The work/school one has an issue where any drafts that are saved (both manually and automatically) do not get deleted from remote server (but I cannot see them locally in thunderbird, as if they were deleted).

Both of them have the same configuration regarding drafts:

[image: Screenshot of "Drafts and Templates" configuration section for the personal account]

I'm honestly super confused because the personal one works perfectly and the only differences I see are the username/password. Furthermore, all other syncing of the drafts folder (eg. creating a message/draft in the web UI and saving it) properly works.

Thunderbird 68.6.0, Windows 10